# Clone or Fork a project after joining to a team

Tags: github, clone, git-fork

As a junior developer, I will start my work in a company next week. 
Since, I worked alone, I don't know I have to clone the whole project and start working on it, or I have to fork the project and send pull request for every changes that I make. I know it may be different in companies but may I ask what companies normally wants in this case? 
It's a big company, but our team contain three developers and one person as a lead development team.

I know this is not a good place to ask, but I will be appreciated if you can help me on this.

Comment: Ask your company. Not us. They will explain their development process.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you have write/push access to the repo, you can just push to (your branch or a feature branch of) the project.

If not, you'll have to fork the project once, work on that fork and create pull requests if you want to merge your code with their repo.

As @JB Nizet commented your question:

> Ask your company. Not us. They will explain their development process.

[**NOTE**]

You can update your fork by pulling from the organisation/team repo and pushing to your fork afterwards.